# Import JS library into Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular

I'd like to import Cleave.js and rellax.js to my project.
I have jquery imported and its working fine. For these libraries I need to write their specific attributes in the html. How can I import these libs?

> angular.json

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/cleave.js/dist/cleave.min.js",
  "node_modules/rellax/rellax.min.js"
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the libraries using Node package manager.

```
npm install --save Cleave
npm install --save rellax
```

Which will download the dependencies & also add it to package.json